# Same program In Two differenct JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, cloud

I have written a program and it's supposed to run on two different JVMs and communicate with each other via JMS. I couln't a way to debug them in Eclipse.

Could you sugget a debugging mechanism for there programs ? They must be run in tow different JVMs. And I have read that JMS is not an appropriate way for being a communication method between these kinf of programs. Can anyone suggest a better approach for ensuring communication between these programs ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing that stops you from starting both of the programs from Eclipse and debugging them both at the same time. Try it!

Comment: Get your program working. Don’t throw it away, just because you have read something somewhere. Since you have implemented the program, you should already know yourself, whether JMS was sufficient to solve your task or needed complicated workarounds. Don’t ask for software recommendations. That’s [off topic for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You can use eclipse to debug two programs. Using JMS or any other messaging solution is not significantly more or less hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the port numbers in both VM. And use the remote debug option in eclipse.

While running App :

java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n myapp

In Eclipse :
Eclipse->Debug->Remotedebug (specify the host address and port.)

Comment: also create remote debug configuration separately for both processes in eclipse.